# django-tables2: sorting does not function on a table of related data

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have two classes: `Project` which has a many-to-one relationship with `Client`. I would like my detailed template of `Client` to display a list of projects that are related to it.

The code below successfully gets the required Projects, and stores them in `context`, which is then passed to the template renderer which renders them successfully.

So far, so good. But the rendered table will not "sort" the data successfully. I can click on the headers, which will add `?sort=name` to the request, but nothing happens.

Is this the correct approach for what I am intending, and if so, what step am I missing to get the full functionality?

models.py

```py
class Client(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=300, unique=True)

class Project(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey("Client", on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=300, unique=True)
```

tables.py

```py
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import *

class ProjectTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ("name", )
```

views.py

```py
class ClientDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Client

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        # Get related Projects and put then in 'table'
        table = ProjectTable(self.object.project_set.all())

        # Add 'table' to 'context'
        context = super(ClientDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['table'] = table

        return context
```

html

```html
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table table %}
```